# questions about this reference in Java

Tags: java

I have a small doubt about this reference in the following program,why the result is "I am in B",my question is how inside the super class constructor we are 
able to access the subclass method.

```
 class A {

      A()
      {this.print();}

      public void print(){    
        System.out.println("I am in class A");
      }
}

class B extends A {

       public void print() {
         System.out.println("I am in class B");
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
         new Stest();
       }
 }
```

Comment: In your code you have called `new Stest()` but where is Stest class?

Comment: Presumably new Stest() should be new B() - that's what I have based my answer on.

Comment: As concernd as java programmer, I'm still an amature. But as far as I know, the super class does know anything about her sub classes. But sub classes does know all about their super class.

Comment: @reporter: you mean to say superclass knows nothing about sub class but sub class knows everything about super class. is it what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Harry Joy Yes. Sry for wrong grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You get "I am in B" because of **runtime polymorphism** or in java terms the print() method in B overrides the print() method in A.
2. Ideally you **should never call non-private methods of non-final classes from base class constructor**. For e.g. in your case, the print() of B gets called from A's constructor but B is not yet initialized, which in your case is fine, but if it used uninitialized fields then....

Comment: thanku suraj for ur nice answar,can u explain the second point more elaborately

Comment: @yagna...let me give u an example. Suppose in your above code, if B class had a boolean variable set to true in B's constrcutor. And this variable is used in B.print(). Now in your case as B.print() will be called even before B's constructor completes, you will still have value of that boolean as false, and hence your code logic can fail :)

Comment: thanks Suraj i am really satisfied with your answer,can you please sujest me some corejava book which can boost my java knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike c++, **Overridden** method is called even the call is made from super class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is polymorphism.  So you are running an instance iniatilizer in A which calls the print method. As the type is actually B it's the method against B which gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how inside the super
>   class constructor we are able to
>   access the subclass method

I'm not sure I understood your question... But if you want to call method print() of A from B you can do it by using the "super" keyword.

```
class B extends A {
       B() { super.print(); }

       public void print() {
         System.out.println("I am in class B");
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
         new Stest();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to object which calls the method. Hence it refers to the class B object. You can refer the link below:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lavender/courses/tutorial/java-05.pdf

Comment: if it refers to class B object,then if we remove the B version print() method from subclass B then why its calling A version print method!!!

Comment: print method in B is an overriding of print method in class A. If you agree to this, answer is clear.